# Simplifying a LINQ expression

Tags: c#, linq

I have a part of code which I really do not like, if it's possible to simplify it somehow - would be really nice.

```
A a; // I want to get rid of this variable
if((a = collection.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Field == null)) != null)
{
  throw new ScriptException("{0}", a.y); //I need to access other field of the object here, that's why I had to declare a variable outside of the expression
}
```

Comment: you'll need the variable unless you want to perform the expression twice

Comment: @Jonesy That's what I was afraid of.

Comment: @Anarion I guess you would be afraid of the `TryParse` and `Tryxxx` pattern.

Comment: What is wrong with it?

Comment: @musefan - here, in a simple example it doesn't look terrible, but in real code - it's not really good.

Comment: @Anarion: Yeah because you have made it horribly unreadable by including the assignment in the if statement

Comment: Quite a discussion you've sparked

Comment: @musefan Yep, I could see it. 10pm, too tired, came to SO for some help.

Comment: @Jonesy I was expecting to get downwoted. But I could't bare seing terrible code in my project. ))

Comment: Really I don't think it's that bad.  That scenario always bugs me too though.  It's not 'terrible', but I like the alternatives better

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can make your code much more readable if you will combine variable assignment and definition:

```
A a = collection.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Field == null);

if(a != null)    
   throw new ScriptException("{0}", a.y);
```

Comment: Thank's. Readable and easy. And thanks to everyone else - many good answers.

Comment: @IAbstract sorry, typo. Fixed!

Comment: Can't choose between this one and @Servy's. Yours is readable and good. Serby's get's "out of box" ))

Comment: @Anarion it's up to you :) Are you writing puzzles or clean self-descriptive code? ;)

Answer (score 8):

Rather than finding the first item that matches and handling that, treat the results as a collection.  `foreach` over all of the items that match using `Where`.  Since the exception will bring you back out of the loop the end result is identical, just with cleaner code:

```
foreach(var a in collection.Where(x => x.Field == null))
    throw new ScriptException("{0}", a.y);
```

If you want to make it clearer to the reader that the loop will only execute once at most, you can add a `Take` call in there to clarify the code without making any functional change:

```
foreach(var a in collection.Where(x => x.Field == null).Take(1))
    throw new ScriptException("{0}", a.y);
```

This also makes it easier to aggregate all of the invalid items, rather than the first:

```
var exceptions = collection.Where(a => a.Field == null)
    .Select(a => new ScriptException("{0}", a.y))
    .ToList();
if (exceptions.Any())
    throw new AggregateException(exceptions);
```

Comment: a good outside-the-box approach, but I would assume that the OP plans on using `a` later on if the exception is not thrown

Comment: Ooh, that's... I dunno, I think that's misleading code since there will never be any iteration of the loop.  It's certainly more concise, but I'd say the original code is more understandable.

Comment: @musefan no, I don't, I wanted to get rid of A.

Comment: @musefan: since the OP explicitly said they don't want to declare `a`, I doubt that's the case :-)

Comment: @DanPuzey There will never be more than one iteration.  That's different than saying there won't ever be any.

Comment: @DanPuzey If it makes you feel better, and improves the readability of the code, you can add a `Take(1)` to make it clearer to the reader that there is never more than one iteration.

Comment: A throw in a loop seems like a code smell to me. In my answer, I collate the y elements, which may be more effective.

Comment: @AlexBeisley Why?  What's wrong with it?  How is it different from a throw in an `if`?  What problems will it cause?

Comment: @AlexBeisley there is nothing wrong with a throw in a for loop. Underneath the hood, it's an enumerator state machine. Granted, it's an implementation of some validation that should probably occur within a specialized collection object, but given that most will not write a specialized collection class just for a single validation process, this is acceptable.

Comment: variable `a` is still here, sitting inside a loop. Also this code is not obvious to understand. Loop which only throws exception? I hope I never will see such things in real code :)

Comment: @lazyberezovsky The point though is that it's not in the outer scope, which appears to be the goal.  You could repeat this code 5 times without needing to change the variable name, unlike your solution, and you're filling the namespace with variables that aren't going to be needed.  Next, what about it is hard to understand?  If there is an item in the sequence it throws an exception, if not, it doesn't.  It's logically of equal complexity to throwing inside of an `if`.

Comment: *you're filling the namespace with variables* - how many lines of code usually your methods have? :) *hard to understand* - you can eat soup with fork, but that's not what fork was designed for. Same here for me

Comment: @lazyberezovsky That depends a lot.  It would seem to me that this method is here to validate preconditions, so this is before the start of the "real" method.  Much like one would null check arguments, for example.  If your code for null checking arguments needed to add a local variable for each argument wouldn't that get annoying when coding?

Comment: @lazyberezovsky What about it is hard to understand?  It reads *exactly* as it functions.  It covers the requirements exactly in fact.  You're simply not as used to dealing with sequences.  You're more experienced with an imperative style of programming rather than a more functional style of programming.  For people coming from different backgrounds from yours this solution can very well be *more* readable.  There's nothing inherently more or less readable about the code as it is; it's simply a pattern you personally aren't used to seeing.  As you see it more, you get used to it.

Answer (score 2):

You can't avoid declaring the variable since you need to assign outside of the `if` and then reference the value inside. (The only way would be to perform the filter twice, which is likely to be expensive).

That said, you can use this to your advantage and make the code more readable:

```
A a = collection.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Field == null); // assign here
if(a != null) // more easily-readable comparison here
{
  throw new ScriptException("{0}", a.y); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't get rid of `A a` in this situation. You need to store the value returned from your LINQ statement to use later, and, unlike a `using` block, an `if` statement doesn't allow you to define a variable in its expression.

Personally, I'd do this:

```
A a = collection.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Field == null);
if(a != null)
{
    throw new ScriptException("{0}", a.y);
}
```

Comment: That's not getting rid of the local variable, as the question is asking for.

Comment: I know. I'm saying it's unavoidable in this situation. I'd do as others have mentioned and combine declaration and assignment to make the code clearer.

Comment: @lazyberezovsky "// I want to get rid of this variable"

Comment: @Servy "if it's possible to simplify it **somehow** - would be really nice" :)

Comment: @lazyberezovsky Yes, he's asking for both.  This does one of those two things, but not the other.

Answer (score 1):

So your logic is: If there are any items with no field, throw an exception.

```
var a = collection.Where(x => x.Field == null);
if(a.Any())
{
  throw new ScriptException("{0}", a.First().y);
}
```

An even better way might be to collate them:

```
var a = collection.Where(x => x.Field == null).Select(x => x.y);
if(a.Any())
{
  throw new ScriptException("{0}", string.Join(',', a));
}
```

That way you can see all of the instances.

Comment: Note that this enumerates the collection twice, rather than just once as all of the other answers do.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `.Select` to remove the outer reference to `a`, although the result is still kind of a mess:

```
collection.Where(x => x.Field == null)
    .Select(a => string.Format("{0}", a.y))
    .Take(1).ToList().ForEach(msg => 
        throw new ScriptException(msg);
    );
```

`Take(1)` returns an empty enumerable if there are no matching items, so that the block in `ForEach` will run either zero or one time.

Comment: That doesn't filter out the items where `Field` is null.

Comment: What kind of `Select` are you using?

Comment: You need to do the filter *before* you select, else you can't access the field, your select is messed up, and this is just a poorer version of the answer that I posted earlier.

Comment: Thanks all ... it's too early, brain is not working very well. (Should be correct now)

Comment: @Servy could you tell me what kind of `Select` he's using? it's so strange to me.

Comment: @KingKing It's not valid, as I said in my comment.  Either he added his own without sharing the implementation, or he omitted a `string.Format` call.

Comment: @KingKing I just left out the `String.Format`.  Fixed now.

Comment: @McGarnagle What's the *point* of the string.format?  It doesn't *do* anything.

Answer (score 0):

Will this work for you? It is ugly, but you can throw the exception within the lambda.

```
collection.FirstOrDefault(x => { 
                                 if(x.Field == null)
                                 {
                                       throw new ScriptException("{0}", x.y);
                                 }
                                 return false;
                                }
                          );
```